# change screen resolution without X accessable

Tags: laptop, kde

I've told KDE to use the external monitor only, and now I'm without external monitor and a black screen. What can I do to reset that?

Answer (score 0):

See if your laptop has a function key for switching between the internal and external monitor. It's usually one of the F1-F12 keys and has a symbol of two monitors on it, like these two:

[image: Laptop function keys]

Once you find the key, press it and the Fn key simultaneously.